# Powergrid table row action button unclickable after modal closed event

Tags: laravel-livewire, livewires, laravel-livewire-wiremodel, livewire-powergrid

**What I have in my laravel project**

1. Livewire powergrid for displaying tables.
2. Livewire-ui-modal (use to have the confirm dialog from the button of the table)

**What I have succeeded**

1. I have displayed my table as accordingly to my requirement using the
   powergrid component.
2. I have put a button  on each row to delete the row. this button
   fires the modal to get the confirmation. It also works.[Livewire Powergrid](https://github.com/Power-Components/livewire-powergrid)
3. I can close the modal when confirm or cancel. I can also trigger
   another event in the powergrid component itself from my modal
   component.It is also fine and can refresh my table in the powergrid
   component.

**What is the problem?**

1. After coming back from the modal(dialog box), other buttons on the powergrid component tables are unclickable.

**Found a Solution here**

I have found the solution in  [https://stackoverflow.com/a/72891828/19714908](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3kPb.png)

It says that there's a conflict between the alpine.js from livewire and alpine.js from @powerGridScripts and he is using @livewireScripts only.

But I think there might be some other drawbacks or impact for not using the @powerGridScripts.
**My Question**
What are the drawbacks of this solution above? Is there any other solution when such conflicts occur?

> ***my layout***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'MSICL') }}</title>

    @livewire('ui.links')
    @livewire('ui.js')
    

    <!-- Styles -->
    @livewireStyles

    @livewireScripts

    @powerGridStyles
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse">
   
    <!-- Site wrapper -->
    <div class="wrapper">
        @livewire('ui.header')
      
        @livewire('ui.sidebar')          
            {{ $slot }}      
     </div>
    {{-- @powerGridScripts --}}
    @livewire('livewire-ui-modal')
</body>
```

[The powergrid table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3kPb.png)

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Approvals;
use App\Models\Approval;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Approvals\MemApprovalController as memApproval;
use App\Http\Controllers\Approvals\MemApprovalController;
use App\Models\Member;
use App\Models\Parameter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use PowerComponents\LivewirePowerGrid\Rules\{Rule, RuleActions};
use PowerComponents\LivewirePowerGrid\Traits\ActionButton;
use PowerComponents\LivewirePowerGrid\Label as label;
use PowerComponents\LivewirePowerGrid\{Button, Column, Exportable, Footer, Header,            PowerGrid, PowerGridComponent, PowerGridEloquent};
 final class member_approval extends PowerGridComponent
   {
   use ActionButton;
   public int $perPage = 10;
   public array $perPageValues = [0,10,15, 20,25, 50,100];
   public string $user_type;
   public ?string $table_name='';
   protected function getListeners(): array
   {
       return array_merge(
       parent::getListeners(), [            
           'refreshMemApproval' => 'refreshTable',             
       ]);
   }
   public function refreshTable()
  {
    $this->refresh();
    // $this->initActions();
    // $this->actions();
    // $this->actionRules();
    return;
  }


public function setUp(): array
{     
    return [
        //    Exportable::make('MemberList_'.date('Ymdhhmm').'_by_'.Auth::user()->display_as)
        //     // ->striped()
        //     ->type(Exportable::TYPE_XLS, Exportable::TYPE_CSV),
        Header::make()
            //
            // ->showSearchInput()
        // ->showToggleColumns()
        ->includeViewOnTop('components.datatable.header-top')
        ,
        Footer::make()
           // ->showPerPage($this->perPage,$this->perPageValues)
            ->showRecordCount()
            ,
    ];
}



public function datasource(): Builder
{
if( MemApprovalController::UserMemberForwardRights())
{
    return  Approval::query()
->join('members as m','m.member_id','approvals.table_ids')
->join('share_infos as shareinfo','shareinfo.member_id','m.member_id')
->join('ins_infos as insinfo','insinfo.member_id','m.member_id')
->select('approvals.*','m.created_date as c_date','m.member_id as member_id','shareinfo.amount as share_amount','insinfo.amount as policy_amount','m.address as address', DB::raw("  CONCAT(
`first_name`,
if(trim(`middle_name`) = ''or isnull(`middle_name`), '', concat(' ', `middle_name`)),
if(trim(`last_name`) = '' or isnull(`last_name`), '', concat(' ', `last_name`))) as full_name"),)
->where('user_type','=',Auth::user()->user_type)
->where('approval_status','=',2)
->orderby('created_date')
->orderby('order')
;
}
elseif( MemApprovalController::UserMemberApproveRights()) {
    return  Approval::query()
->join('members as m','m.member_id','approvals.table_ids')
->join('share_infos as shareinfo','shareinfo.member_id','m.member_id')
->join('ins_infos as insinfo','insinfo.member_id','m.member_id')
->select('approvals.*','m.created_date as c_date','m.member_id as member_id','shareinfo.amount as share_amount','insinfo.amount as policy_amount','m.address as address', DB::raw("  CONCAT(
`first_name`,
if(trim(`middle_name`) = ''or isnull(`middle_name`), '', concat(' ', `middle_name`)),
if(trim(`last_name`) = '' or isnull(`last_name`), '', concat(' ', `last_name`))) as full_name"),
)
->where('user_type','=',Auth::user()->user_type)
->where('approval_status','=','2')
->where('m.status','=','F')
->orderby('created_date')
->orderby('order')
;
}
else {
    return  Approval::query()
    ->join('members as m','m.member_id','approvals.table_ids')
    ->join('share_infos as shareinfo','shareinfo.member_id','m.member_id')
    ->join('ins_infos as insinfo','insinfo.member_id','m.member_id')
    ->select('approvals.*','m.created_date as c_date','m.member_id as member_id','shareinfo.amount as share_amount','insinfo.amount as policy_amount','m.address as address', DB::raw("  CONCAT(
`first_name`,
if(trim(`middle_name`) = ''or isnull(`middle_name`), '', concat(' ', `middle_name`)),
if(trim(`last_name`) = '' or isnull(`last_name`), '', concat(' ', `last_name`))) as full_name"),)
->where('user_type','=',Auth::user()->user_type)
->where('approval_status','=',1)
->orderby('created_date')
->orderby('order')
;
}  
}  
public function relationSearch(): array
{
    return [];
}   
public function addColumns(): PowerGridEloquent
{
    return PowerGrid::eloquent()
        ->addColumn('id')
        ->addColumn('table_name')
       /** Example of custom column using a closure **/
        ->addColumn('table_name_lower', function (Approval $model) {
            return strtolower(e($model->table_name));
        })
        ->addColumn('table_ids')
        ->addColumn('full_name')
        ->addColumn('share_amount')
        ->addColumn('policy_amount')
        ->addColumn('address')
        ->addColumn('c_date')
        ->addColumn('c_date_formatted', fn (Approval $model) => Carbon::parse($model->created_date)->format('d/m/Y'))
        ->addColumn('user_type')
        ->addColumn('approval_mode')
        ->addColumn('member_id')
        ->addColumn('approval_status')          
        ->addColumn('status')
        ->addColumn('approved_date_formatted', fn (Approval $model) => Carbon::parse($model->approved_date)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'))
        ->addColumn('approved_by')
        ->addColumn('created_by')
        ->addColumn('created_date_formatted', fn (Approval $model) => Carbon::parse($model->created_date)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'))
        ->addColumn('updated_by')
        ->addColumn('updated_date_formatted', fn (Approval $model) => Carbon::parse($model->updated_date)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'));
}   
public function columns(): array
{
    return [          
       Column::make('date', 'c_date_formatted')         
        ,
        Column::make('Member ID', 'table_ids')            
           ,
           Column::make('Full NAME', 'full_name')
           ->bodyAttribute('any-class','min-width: 20 vw;max-width:20 vw')             
               ->searchable()               
               ,
        Column::make('MEMBER ID', 'member_id')
         ->hidden(true,true),
         Column::make('Share Amount', 'share_amount')
            //->makeInputRange()
             ,
             Column::make('Insurance Amount', 'policy_amount')
             //->makeInputRange()
              ,
              Column::make('Address', 'address')
              //->makeInputRange()
               ,           
    ]
 ;
}
public function actions(): array
{
    
   
    $button_label='Approve';
    
    if (memApproval::UserMemberForwardRights()) {
        $button_label='Forward';
    }
    
    $button=[
        Button::make('view', 'View')
        ->class('bg-info bg-gradient btn cursor-pointer text-white px-3 py-1 border border-white text-sm')              
        ->route('members.member.show', ['member' => 'member_id'])
        ->target('_self')
        ->method('get'),
        Button::make('approve', $button_label)
        ->class('bg-success bg-gradient btn cursor-pointer text-white px-3 py-1 border border-white text-sm')              
        ->route('approvals.memapproval.action', ['approval' => 'id','action'=>strtolower($button_label)])
        ->target('_self')
        ->method('put'),
        Button::make('reject', 'Reject')
        ->class('bg-danger bg-gradient btn cursor-pointer text-white px-3 py-1 border border-white text-sm')              
        // ->route('approvals.memapproval.action', ['approval' => 'id','action'=>'reject'])
        // ->target('_self')
        // ->method('put')
        ->openModal('approvals.member-action', [
            'approval_id'     => 'id',
            'action'    =>'reject',
            'confirmationTitle'       => 'Reject Member',
            'confirmationDescription' => 'Are you sure you want to reject this member?'])
            ,
        Button::make('status','waiting')
        ->class('bg-transparent border-0 text-red-500 text-sm p-0 cursor-pointer') ,            

        ];
        
   return $button;
}



public function actionRules(): array
{
   return [

       //Hide button edit for ID 1
        Rule::button('approve')

            ->when(function ($approve) { 
                return !memApproval::UserMemberApproveOrder($approve->member_id) ;
            })              
                ->hide(),
            Rule::button('reject')

                ->when(function ($approve) { 
                    return !memApproval::UserMemberApproveOrder($approve->member_id) ;
                })              
                    ->hide(),
         Rule::button('view')
                ->when(function () { 
                    return !memApproval::UserMemberViewRights() ;
                })
                ->hide(),
        Rule::button('status')
                ->when(function ($row) { 
                    return memApproval::UserMemberApproveOrder($row->member_id) ;                          
                })
                ->hide(),
            ];
}}
```

> **The modal component**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Livewire\Approvals;

 use App\Http\Controllers\Approvals\MemApprovalController;
 use App\Http\Livewire\Approvals\member_approval;
 use Livewire\Component;

 use LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent;

class memberAction extends ModalComponent
{
public ?int $approval_id = null;

public array $approval_ids = [];
public string $action='';

public string $confirmationTitle = '';

public string $confirmationDescription = '';
public static function modalMaxWidth(): string
{
    return 'md';
}

public static function closeModalOnEscape(): bool
{
    return false;
}

public static function closeModalOnClickAway(): bool
{
    return false;
}
public static function destroyOnClose(): bool
{
    return true;
}

public function cancel()
{
    $this->closeModal();
}

public function confirm()
{
    if ($this->approval_id) {
        $message=MemApprovalController::Action($this->approval_id,$this->action);
        // return back()->with('success_message','Application rejected !');
       // route('approvals.memapproval.action', ['approval' =>         $this->approval_id,'action'=>$this->action]);
        //Dish::query()->find($this->dishId)->delete();
    }

    if ($this->approval_ids) {
        //Dish::query()->whereIn('id', $this->dishIds)->delete();
    }
    //$this->emitTo(member_approval::class, 'pg:eventRefresh-default');
    


    $this->closeModalWithEvents([
        'refreshMemApproval',
    ]);
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.approvals.member-action');
}
```

}